# How would you model this non-relational database?

Tags: graph, neo4j

I am making a graph database using Neo4j and I'm wondering what's the best way to model this case:

Person1 > told > quote > to > Person2 > who told it to -> Person3 -> who told it to -> Person4 > Who told it to -> Person1

I've thought about quote being an attribute of link. But then maybe quote needs also to be a node. In this case the edges would be "told" and "was_told". Like:

Person1 -> created > quote
Quote attributes: id, text 
Person attributes: id, name

Person2 > told: {to: Person 3} > quote
Person3 > was_told: {by: Person2} > quote

or:

Person3 > told:quote > Person1

What's the best approach to use to model this database?

Comment: This is a pretty interesting problem. Can you add on the kind of queries and operations you expect to be performing (just a general description, not in cypher or pseudocode)? That might add weight to one kind of modeling over another.

Answer (score 3):

I think you need the following model:

> - A fragment (talk) of a conversation (including time)
> - Who was the speaker of this fragment
> - Who was an audience of this fragment
> - Content (quote) of this fragment

For example, here's the [code](https://gist.github.com/stdob/62d7b07737c3cb6a532175aef9ea92dd#file-01-cypher-data-md) for creating the first fragment:

```
MERGE (P1:Person {name:'Person1'})
MERGE (P2:Person {name:'Person2'})
MERGE (Q:Quote {name:'Quote1', text:'Quote1 text'})
MERGE (P1)<-[:has_speaker]-(T1:Talk {name:'Talk1', time: 1})-[:has_audience]->(P2)
MERGE (T1)-[:talk_about]->(Q)
```

Visualization:

[image]

The query for the entire life cycle of a quote:

```
MATCH (Q:Quote {name:'Quote1', text:'Quote1 text'})<-[:talk_about]-(T:Talk)
WITH Q, T
MATCH (P1:Person)<-[:has_speaker]-(T)-[:has_audience]->(P2) 
WITH Q, T, P1 as speaker, collect(P2.name) as audience ORDER BY T.time ASC
RETURN Q as quote, 
       collect( {time: T.time, 
                 speaker: speaker.name, 
                 audience: audience} 
       ) as quoteTimeline
```

Comment: Extracting out a Talk (or Conversation or even a Shared) node definitely seems like the right kind of solution. I think the only thing that might be missing is a relation between the talks, something like (talk1)<-[:SharedFrom]-(talk2), and so on. That way, if there are multiple talk chains (or talk trees, if you're allowing one person to share with multiple people instead of just one), you can identify and find each chain about a quote, or trace through a chain.